# PHP Append an array to a sub array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to make an array of locations arrays, it must look like this

```
$relevanceKeys = array(
    'locations' => array(

        array(
            'longitude' => '123456',
            'latitude' => '123456'
        ),
        array(
            'longitude' => '123456',
            'latitude' => '123456'
        )
         ... more arrays
    )  

);
```

However I need to generate those on the fly, so it starts out like

```
$relevanceKeys = array(
    'locations' => array(  

    )  
);
```

And then I want to add each array from a row I found in the database:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
   $array = array(
               array (
       'longitude' => $row->longitude,
        'latitude' => $row->latitude
           )
   );

$relevanceKeys['locations'] = $relevanceKeys['locations'] + $array;
}
```

This does not work though, afterwards the file is not readable.  It's exported to a different format so I can't see if it turns into the array tree correctly.

I read how to append PHP arrays from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

I tried unnested `$array` and nested in another array as it is now, no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append the array like this:

```
$relevanceKeys['locations'][] = $array;
                         //^^ See here
```

You don't have to merge them all the time!

Also I think you want to change this:

```
$array = array(
             array (
                 'longitude' => $row->longitude,
                 'latitude' => $row->latitude
             )
       );
```

to this to get your expected structure:

```
$array = array(
             'longitude' => $row->longitude,
             'latitude' => $row->latitude
       );
```

For more information about array see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Kiwizoom You can also read about this specificly here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only needing to push elements to the array, you can simply use the `[]` struct as follows:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
{
    $relevanceKeys['locations'][] = array (
        'longitude' => $row->longitude,
        'latitude' => $row->latitude
    );
}
```